# How to force user to enter value of a method parameter in one of two types without overloading

Tags: c#, parameters

I'm working on a C# project, I have this method

```
    private static Encryption_Model Enc(byte[] PlainData,byte[] Key)
    {

        //Some logic code here

    }
```

the parameter `Key` I want user to enter it in one of two types `byte[]` or `int`.

**Is there any way to force user to enter the Key parameter in one of two types `byte[]` or `int` without using overloading ?**

Massive thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

No, overloads are meant for this. Why don't you want that?

Sure, you could add two default parameters and throw if neither or both are provided:

```
private static Encryption_Model Enc(byte[] plainData, byte[] keyBytes = null, int? keyInt = null)
{
    if ((keyBytes == null && keyInt == null) 
        || (keyBytes != null && keyInt != null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Provide either keyBytes or keyInt");
    }
}
```

But that's just nasty, as now your method has to go and figure out which parameter is provided and how to use either, and it doesn't give compile-time safety. This does:

```
private static Encryption_Model Enc(byte[] plainData, int key)
{
    var keyBytes = GetBytesFromInt(key); // Probably BitConverter.GetBytes()
    return Enc(plainData, keyBytes);
}

private static Encryption_Model Enc(byte[] plainData, byte[] key)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The second solution you suggested is interested, massive thanks for your time sir

Comment: But that's an overload. Why did you think you don't want that?

Comment: Yeah I know, I just want to ignore many overloads for this method, but if I didn't found any solution without overloading I will go back using overloading at the end, If you have any other solution I appreciate  it  for you sir